# Como somar valores de listas em tuplos?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tenho por exemplo uma lista com tuplos, e dentro desses tuplos tenho 2 listas, onde só a segunda lista de cada tuplo varia:
`x= [(y, [1, 2]), (y, [3,4]), (y, [5, 6])]`

Como faço para somar os primeiros valores das listas dentro do tuplos, assim:

```
1+3+5 = 9
2+4+6 = 12
Ficando: [9, 12]
```

Nota: Eu só quero somar os valores das segundas listas de cada tuplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer algo como:

```
x= [('y', [1, 2]), ('y', [3,4]), ('y', [5, 6])]
soma = [0]*2
for t in x:
    soma[0] += t[1][0]
    soma[1] += t[1][1]
print soma
```

Isso retornará:

```
[9,12]
```

#### Edit

Pra adequar a resposta ao seu comentário, uma possibilidade é fazer o seguinte:

```
x = [('y', [1, 2]), ('y', [3,4]), ('y', [5, 6])]
soma = []
for t in x:
    for i in xrange(len(t[1])):
        if i == len(soma):
            soma.append(0)
        soma[i] += t[1][i]
print soma
```

Comment: sim isso está certo, só que há um problema. Essas minhas listas dentro de tuplos podem mudar de tamanho, e os tuplos também. ou seja, as listas podes ser de n elementos e podem existir n tuplos

Comment: n tuplas dentro dessa lista ou n tuplas dentro das tuplas?

Comment: eu tenho uma lista de tuplas, e dentro dessas tuplas tenho outras listas, que as podemos chamar de listas2. Eu dentro das listas posso ter n tuplas e dentro das listas2 posso ter vários valores, ou seja, pode ficar assim:x= [('y', [1, 2, 3, 4]), ('y', [5, 6, 7, 8]), ('y', [9, 10, 11, 12]), (13,14,15,16)]

Comment: Não entendi essa última tupla, mas não seria possível padronizar a tupla pra ter sempre um valor e uma lista nela?

Comment: pois enganei-me, ficaria: x= [('y', [1, 2, 3, 4]), ('y', [5, 6, 7, 8]), ('y', [9, 10, 11, 12]), (y,[13,14,15,16])]

Comment: @Romy, veja se a minha edição resolve o seu problema. (:

Answer (score 4):

Em [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) existe uma variante do [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) que, ao combinar listas de tamanhos diferentes, não descarta os elementos a mais, e sim usa `None` para seus valores:

```
>>> teste = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]
>>> list(izip_longest(*teste))
[(1, 4, 6), (2, 5, 7), (3, None, 8), (None, None, 9)]
```

<sub>[Crédito](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17521272/520779)</sub>

Ou, se especificado um valor padrão via `fillvalue`, esse valor é usado (bom para atribuir zero e não interferir com a soma):

```
>>> teste = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]
>>> list(izip_longest(*teste, fillvalue=0))
[(1, 4, 6), (2, 5, 7), (3, 0, 8), (0, 0, 9)]
```

Assim, pode-se usar algumas compreensões de lista para se obter a lista das somas num único comando:

```
>>> x= [(y, [1, 2, 3]), (y, [4, 5]), (y, [6, 7, 8, 9])]
>>> somas = [sum(numeros) for numeros in
...   izip_longest(*[segundo for primeiro,segundo in x], fillvalue=0)
... ]
>>> somas
[11, 14, 11, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solução de uma linha, sem usar `import` nem `for`:

```
>>> sum([b[0] for a, b in x]), sum([b[1] for a,b in x])
(9, 12)
```

Versão que retorna uma lista:

```
>>> [sum([b[0] for a, b in x]), sum([b[1] for a,b in x])]
[9, 12]
```

Comment: Essa solução não esta preparada para tuplas de tamanhos diferentes.

Comment: Correto Mauro, mas esse requisito não estava explícito na pergunta colocada.